# Pass my df from panddf function,pass it as paramater to graphview function

Tags: python, django, pandas, matplotlib, django-views

In this code i reutrned pie chart for all my data in database.. Now I have filtered my data using pandas df in panddf funtion and I need to pass my df into graphview function to get pie chart only for my filtered dataframe

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from board.models import userboard
from.utils import get_plot
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def graphview(request):
 
     qs =userboard.obects.all()
     x=[x.Month for x in qs]
     y=[y.Bp_Values for y in qs]
     chart = get_plot(x,y)

     return render(request, 'piechart.html' ,{'chart':chart})


def panddf(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
        print(username)
    engine=create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:#24May@2002@localhost/bhavesh')
    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM public."board_userboard"',con=engine)
    filt = (df['User_name'] == username)
    print(df[filt])
    df1 = (df[filt])
  
    return render(request, 'abc.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ?

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from board.models import userboard
from.utils import get_plot
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def graphview(request):
 
     qs =userboard.objects.all()
     x=[x.Month for x in qs]
     y=[y.Bp_Values for y in qs]
     chart = get_plot(x,y)

     return render(request, 'piechart.html' ,{'chart':chart})


def panddf(request):
     username = None
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
         username = request.user.username
         print(username)
     qs =userboard.objects.filter(User_name=username)
     x=[x.Month for x in qs]
     y=[y.Bp_Values for y in qs]
     chart = get_plot(x,y)

     return render(request, 'piechart.html' ,{'chart':chart})
```

Comment: Can you add the model.py to the question ?

Comment: yeah i got my piechart at first but now it throws an error 'type object 'userboard' has no attribute 'obects'

Comment: There was a typo also in the graphview

Comment: sry dint notice!!

Comment: Please add the model.py and the exact error you are getting

Comment: Got my output sir..Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: Sir can u clear me this doubt please??I want to get my value for month and values from front end..If I get those values  in a single page it would be saved as 12 columns..How can i add each entry in a single row..For example if its jan and the value is 180,It must be in one row..Can u help me sorting this out sir??

Comment: Sorry I do not understand, can you show me an example of what you are trying to get ?